# Bidirectional path tracing, algorithm explanation

Tags: algorithm, raytracing

I'm trying to understand path tracing. So far, I have only dealt with the very basis - when a ray is launched from each intersection point in a random direction within the hemisphere, then again, and so on recursively, until the ray hits the light source. As a result, this approach leads to the fact that in the case of small light sources, the image is extremely noisy.

The following images show the noise level depending on the number of samples (rays) per pixel.
[image: Noise level]

*I am also not sure that i am doing everything correctly, because the "Monte Carlo" method, as far as I understand, implies that several rays are launched from each intersection point, and then their result is summed and averaged. But this approach leads to the fact that the number of rays increases exponentially, and after 6 bounces reaches inadequate values, so i decided that it is better to just run several rays per pixel initially (slightly shifted from the center of the pixel in a random direction), but only 1 ray is generated at each intersection. I do not know whether this approach corresponds to "Monte Carlo" or not, but at least this way the rendering does not last forever..*

**Bidirectional path tracing**

I started looking for ways to reduce the amount of noise, and came across bidirectional path tracing. But unfortunately, i couldn't find a detailed explanation of this algorithm in simple words. All I understood is that the rays are generated from both the camera and the light sources, and then there is a check on the possibility of connecting the endpoints of these paths.

[image]

As you can see, if the intersection points of the blue ray from the camera and the white ray from the light source can be freely connected (there are no obstacles in the connection path), then we can assume that the ray from the camera can pass through the points y1, y0 directly to the light source.

But there are a lot of questions:

1. If the light source is not a point, but has some shape, then the point from which the ray is launched must be randomly selected on the surface of this shape? If you take only the center - then there will be no difference from a point light source, right?
2. Do i need to build a path from the light source for each path from the camera, or should there be only one path from the light source, while several paths (samples) are built from the camera for one pixel at once?
3. The number of bounces/re-reflections/refractions should be the same for the path from the camera and the light source? Or not?

But the questions don't end there. I have heard that the bidirectional trace method allows you to model caustics well (in comparison with regular path tracing). But I completely did not understand how the method of bidirectional path tracing can somehow help for this.

**Example 1**

[image]

Here the path will eventually be built, but the number of bounces will be extremely large, so no caustics will work here, despite the fact that the ray from the camera is directed almost to the same point where the path of the ray from the light source ends.

**Example 2**

[image]

Here the path will not be built, because there is an obstacle between the endpoints of the paths, although it could be built if point x3 was connected to point y1, but according to the algorithm (if I understand everything correctly), only the last points of the paths are connected.

**Question:**

What is the use of such an algorithm, if in a significant number of cases the paths either cannot be built, or are unnecessarily long? Maybe I misunderstand something? I came across many articles and documents where this algorithm was somehow described, but mostly it was described mathematically (using all sorts of magical terms like biased-unbiased, PDF, BSDF, and others), and not.. algorithmically. I am not that strong in mathematics and all sorts of mathematical notation and wording, I would just like to understand WHAT TO DO, how to implement it correctly in the code, how these paths are connected, in what order, and so on. This can be explained in simple words, pseudocode, right? I would be extremely grateful if someone would finally shed some light on all this.

Comment: I am not an expert, but I guess you should post your question in other forums. I hardly see rendering guys in stackoverflow. I may suggest: https://forum.beyond3d.com/forums/rendering-technology-and-apis.40/, or, gavedev: https://www.gamedev.net/forums/. Even reddit has some specialized community.

Comment: Your question isn’t a bad question as such but I don’t really think Stack Overflow is the right forum for it. It’s too broad a topic for a single question. I suggest posting in a more rendering-focused forum and returning here when you have specific questions about how to implement path tracing.

Answer (score 0):

Some references that helped me to understand the Path tracing right :

- https://www.scratchapixel.com/ (every rendering student should begin with this)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_tracing

If you're looking for more references, path tracing is used for "Global illumination" wich is the opposite as "Direct illumination" that only rely on a straight line from the point to the light.

What's more caustics is well knowned to be a hard problem, so don't begin with it! Monte Carlo method is a good straightforward method to begin with, but it has its limitations (ie Caustics and tiny lights).

### Some advices for rendering newbees

Mathematics notations are surely not the coolest ones. Every one will of course prefer a ready to go code. But maths is the most rigourous way to describe the world. It permits also to modelize a whole physic interaction in a small formula instead of plenty of lines of codes that doesn't fit to the real problem. I suggest you to forget you to try reading what you read better as a good mathematic formula is always detailed. If some variables are not specified, don't loose your time and search another reference.